# Drop down menu not appearing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have multiple drop down menus. Depending on what's selected in the first drop down menu, the second drop down menu changes. Im currently trying to add a third drop down menu that changes depending on what's selected in the second menu, but i cant even get the options in the third drop down menu to show up

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";

const App = () => {
  /** "selected" here is state variable which will hold the
   * value of currently selected dropdown.
   */
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");
  const [subSelected, setSubSelected] = React.useState("");

  /** Function that will set different values to state variable
   * based on which dropdown is selected
   */
  const changeSelectOptionHandler = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
  };


  const changeSubSelectOptionHandler = (event) => {
    setSubSelected(event.target.value);
  };


  /** Different arrays for different dropdowns */
  const PVC_Water = ["4\"", "6\"", "8\"", "10\"", "12\"", "14\"", "16\"", "18\"", "20\"", "24\"", "30\"", "36\"", "42\"", "48\"", "54\"", "60\""];
  const PVC_Gravity = ["4\"", "6\"", "8\"", "10\"", "12\"", "15\"", "18\"", "21\"", "24\"", "27\"", "30\"", "36\"", "42\"", "48\"", "54\"", "60\""];

  /** Type variable to store different array for different dropdown */
  let type = null;
  let subType = null;

  /** This will be used to create set of options that user will see */
  let options = null;
  let subOptions = null;


  /** Setting Type variable according to dropdown */
  if (selected === "PVC for Water Mains") {
    type = PVC_Water;
  } else if (selected === "PVC for Gravity Sewer") {
    type = PVC_Gravity;
  }

  if (subSelected === "4\"") {
    subType = ["option 1", "option 2"];
  } else {
    subType = null;
  }

  /** If "Type" is null or undefined then options will be null,
   * otherwise it will create a options iterable based on our array
   */
  if (type) {
    options = type.map((el) => <option key={el}>{el}</option>);
  }

  if (subType) {
    subOptions = subType.map((el) => <option key={el}>{el}</option>);
  }

  return (
      <div
          style={{
            padding: "16px",
            margin: "16px",
          }}
      >
        <form>
          <div>
            {/** Bind changeSelectOptionHandler to onChange method of select.
             * This method will trigger every time different
             * option is selected.
             */}
            <select onChange={changeSelectOptionHandler}>
              <option>Choose...</option>
              <option>PVC for Water Mains</option>
              <option>PVC for Gravity Sewer</option>
              <option>PVC Pressure Rated (IPS)</option>
              <option>Ductile Iron Pipe</option>
              <option>HDPE Pipe (IPS)</option>
              <option>HDPE Pipe (DIPS)</option>
              <option>Steel (NPS)</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select>
              {
                /** This is where we have used our options variable */
                options
              }
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select onChange={changeSubSelectOptionHandler}>
              {
                /** This is where we have used our subOptions variable */
                subOptions
              }
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Im trying to get the value from the second drop down menu correctly, but it doesn't seem like its working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, it's doing what you wrote.
In the second select you're missing the onChange function where you have to set your 3rd filter values